# How do I set the size of the text I'm drawing here?

Tags: ios, text, nsstring

I'm drawing some text using the code below.  How do I set the size of this text?

```
NSDictionary *attrs =
    @{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor grayColor],
       };
NSString *currentRank = @"Sample text";
[currentRank drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(100, 100) withAttributes:attrs];
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the docs it seems as though the font name contains the size

> **NSFontAttributeName**
>   NSFont
>   Default Helvetica 12-point
>   Available in OS X v10.0 and later.
>   Declared in NSAttributedString.h.